# WPF Data Binding and Formatting

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a bool property in my ViewModel called `IsConnected` and I would like to bind it to a TextBlock in my MainWindow. Rather than have the textblock read `true` or `false` I need it to say `Connected` or `Disconnected` instead. Forgive me because I'm new to WPF. If someone could give me a head start I can take it from there but I'm not sure how to figure out what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd generally prefer to just add a property to the view model (I really dislike value converters), but here's a simple way to accomplish what you're trying to do using a style:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="Text" Value="Connected"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Text" Value="Disconnected"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

**Edit**

Note that once you get used to using data triggers, you can make all kinds of modifications to your view without touching your view model.  For instance:

```
<StackPanel>
   <Image Source="images\connected.png">
     <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </Image.Style>
  </Image>
   <Image Source="images\disconnected.png">
     <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </Image.Style>
  </Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This seems to be a better solution to the problem. I'm not really thinking that a converter is such a good idea. Styles seem like a better fit and I don't have to make a helper property to generate string values. I'd rather keep my ViewModel data as the data it's intended to be.

Comment: Worked great and thanks for image example because I'm wanting to do something similar in my view for another property.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is probably to create a custom converter which converts your bool value to a string. Search anywhere for IValueConverter and/or WPF.

```
public class BoolToConnectedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       if((bool)value)
             return "Connected";
       else
             return "Disconnected";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

add xmlns:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyProjectNameSpace"
```

add resource to XAML (change to whatever element needed)

```
<Window.Resources>
  <converter:BoolToConnectedConverter x:Key="connectedConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource connectedConverter}" />
```

Comment: The only change i would make to this is to retrieve the text from a string resource file. That way you can make it a nice generic  `BoolToString` converter, and use the converter parameter to pass in the prefix of the resource key to use (prefix + bool value == complete key required to retrieve string from resource).

Comment: @slugster, I agree with that. Thought about it for a moment, but discarded it in sake of simplicity for this sample.

Comment: I dislike value converters.  They're black boxes that often contain subtle errors that don't arise unless you test them rigorously.  This one, for instance, throws an exception if the value it's converting isn't boolean.  Should it?  And why is it OK to not convert back?  The answer is because this isn't a real converter; it's a one-off hack in support of a view.  You can't tell from looking at the XAML whether or a converter it's using is a real converter or just a quick hack.  This becomes an issue once your projects start getting large.

Answer (score 1):

Using ViewModel, you write two property wrap, and notify changes in the real property.

So that whenever the value is changed, you the string representation will update and bind to controls, while you can still use the bool property in the code.

```
public string IsConnectedStr{
  get{
    return IsConnected?"Connected":"Disconnected";
  }
}

public bool IsConnected{
   get{
     return _isConnected;
   }
   set{
     _isConnected=value;
     PropertyChanged("IsConnected");
     PropertyChanged("IsConnectedStr");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two ways

1) Write a converter

2) Change the function in the ViewModel so that it returns the desired string instead of a bool

The easiest way is  #2, but if you really need the bool value somewhere else in your code you go with #1 (google converter and wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at value converters.

http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

```
public class BoolToConnectedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isConnected = (bool)value;
        return isConnected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not required for read-only values");
    }
}
```

In your XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <l:BoolToConnectedConverter x:Key="boolToConnectedConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource boolToConnectedConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```